# The level set of convolution

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, elliptic-pde

Suppose $u\in C^2(\bar \Omega)\cap C^\infty(\Omega)$ is a function which is compact supported on $\Omega$ with $u\equiv 0$ at $\partial\Omega$, and $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^3$.

We also assume that $\Omega$ is actually a 3-D ellipse centered at origin, i.e. 
$$  \Omega=\{(x,y,z);ax^2+by^2+cz^2<1\} $$

Now, suppose we know that the level set of $u$ is proportional to the boundary of $\Omega$, i.e., it is just a scaled version of $\Omega$. I am interesting in to see  what the level set of function
$$ u\ast \Gamma $$
looks like. Here $\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution of Laplace solution, i.e., 
$$ \Gamma(x)=\frac{1}{|x|} $$

Thank you!

---

Thanks for @Joonas IImavirta's reply. I think the super level sets of $u\ast \Gamma$ should be convex, but I can't proof it. If you could provide me some reference that would be awesome. Also, I do want to know how the super level sets of $u\ast \Gamma$ depend on $f$, where $f$ is defined in @Joonas IImavirta's comment.

Comment: It seems that if the superlevel sets of $u$ are scaled versions of $\Omega=\{(x,y,z);ax^2+by^2+cz^2<1\}$ (is this what you mean?), then $u$ is of the form $u(x,y,z)=f(ax^2+by^2+cz^2)$ for a monotone function $f$ with $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)=0$. Do you want to know how the superlevel sets of $u*\Gamma$ depend on $f$, or do you perhaps want to know some general properties like convexity?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I updated my post. Please have a look. Thank you!